# What does the expression ''keep track so'' in the sentence: ''kep track so you're doing it every day'' mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, expressions

I was watching a video on YouTube about English tips and the YouTuber said a sentence that I didn't understand.

> Keep track so you're doing this every day.

I looked at the YouTube translation, but it went like this:

> Record everything so you can do this every day.

The expression "keep track", in translation, gained the meaning of "keep control". What does the expression "maintain control" in this sentence mean? Soon after, the YouTuber said, "write every day what you do." That sentence I understood. But the specific meaning of "keep track" in the phrase "keep track so you're doing it every day" has me confused. The meaning of "keep track" in this context would be "annotate, write"?

Answer (score 1):

["Keep track" is an idiom](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/keep-track-of). It means knowing about all the happenings/changes of a particular thing. It might involve writing things down so you can keep a better track of things.

Comment: Yes, but it is usually keep track of something and here the author chose to leaven that out.